# Algorithm to estimate time complexity of another algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is it possible to develop an algorithm to estimate the time complexity of another  algorithm? I mean, the input would be some algorithm and the output could be the time complexity of it (Big-Oh, Big-Omega, and so on). I could not find anything about it on the web.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about asymptotic runtime complexity should be posted on cs.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228634/287333).

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know about this. I will post it there. Thanks :)

Comment: Not, it isn't possible to write an algorithm that would work on all inputs. If it was, you could use it to solve the halting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me extend @interjay's comment a little bit.

The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is asking

> if it possible to design a Turing Machine (you may think it as an program in you computer) such that given a Turing Machine (again, think it as a program) it can decide whether or not this input Turing Machine will terminate eventually.

One can prove that it is impossible to design such a Turing Machine. Now let consider you question, if you are able to design an algorithm as you
want, you will be able to answer whether a given Turing Machine will terminate or not.  That is unfortunately impossible.

Above argument is called "Reduction" which is one of the most popular way to show a given problem is unsolvable.